# Disable actionSheet which is used as a picker for IOS

Tags: react-native, actionsheet

I am using react-native-actionsheet. How can I disable the ActionSheet which is used as a Picker (make it not clickable)?

I tried: `editable={false}`.  Are there bettter approaches?

```
                <View style={styles.Column}>
                  <Text style={styles.TextLabel} onPress={this.showActionSheet}>Structure Type:</Text>
                    <ActionSheet
                  ref={o => this.ActionSheet = o}
                  title={'Structure Type'}
                  options={['first', 'second', 'third', 'Cancel']}
                  cancelButtonIndex={3}
                  selectedValue={this.state.structureType}
                  value={this.state.structureType}
                  onPress={this.handleSTypePress}
                  editable={false}
                />
                </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding pointerEvents="none" to the column view